# Does the Normalize.css works fine if I add it as second css stylesheet or does it overwrite something?

Tags: html, css, sass

as above mentioned i am not sure if my CSS file for resetting the default browser settings works fine if I add it as a second stylesheet link. Can u help me? Thanks

Comment: No, that won't work. normalize.css will overwrite the previous matching CSS rules as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize.css overwrites **lots** of things. That's the point of it.

Your rules **might** be written in such a way that they are more specific that the ones in normalize.css, or they might not.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize.css is a CSS(Cascading Style Sheets) file that provides better cross-browser consistency in the default styling of HTML elements. It corrects  different kind of common  bugs in browsers.Such as,

1. common desktop and mobile browser bugs that are out of scope for resets,
2. display settings for HTML5 elements,
3. correcting font-size for preformatted text etc..

So as above mentioned, Normalize.css contain styles that apply globally to all native HTML elements. So if you import **Normalize.css** **not as the first stylesheet** of your project may override some other importent styles which you have declared in other CSS files which you imported before the Normalize.css file.

I hope that below link will be helpful for you:
https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssnormalize/

Comment: Thank you, i will put it as first link. So that the file does what it is intended for.